# Spring MVC mocking

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am trying to use Spring MVC mock module to unit test my controllers. I have added this:

```
    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        standaloneSetup(new CarController());
    }
```

which works fine. However I have created a controller advice that have a method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler`. I want to test that it works during unit testing. I saw that I can build a `MockMvc` object and pass that to `standaloneSetup(..)`:

```
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(
    new CarController()).setHandlerExceptionResolvers(...).build();
```

However when I do this the test that checks that the exception handler works passes but all the other tests that access the response with jsonpath fails with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected response body to be verified as JSON,
    HTML or XML but content-type 'null' is not supported out of the box.
Try registering a custom parser using:
   RestAssured.registerParser("null", <parser type>);
Content was:
```

How do I fix this? What is wrong?

**Bottom line is that I want to unit test my rest api. How should I do this when I have added a exception handler for instance?**

Comment: This link might help you since the author is also showing how to test rest api for an expected exception, among other tests. > http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-rest-api/

Comment: Can you give an example of test that fails and one that passes? We'd have to see your exception handler and controller method.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the usage a bit. I will look at Spring MVC test framework without Rest Assured and try some of your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bottom line is that I want to unit test my rest api. How should I do
>   this when I have added a exception handler for instance?

For one I would use the built in spring mock framework, available from version 3.2, and not rest assured (it might be good, but can;t imagine it is integrated as well). This might cover the basics of [getting started](http://socialgastro.wordpress.com/java-spring-mvc-3-2/testing-multiple-controllers-spring-3-2/).

Secondly, you can just `try and catch` in your test method, then assert on a boolean as to whether a exception was thrown. Or test for whether an exception message was returned from controller doing an expect on status code 500, for example. This will depend on your api.

Comment: You were the first one to lead me in the right direction. I have read the documentation of Spring testing and I got it working. Spring MVC Framework is the answer. I guess I managed to mix classes from two different frameworks etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try using accept():

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/hotels/{id}", 42).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

You can also set the return type when building MockMvc.

```
mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new AccountController())
        .defaultRequest(get("/")
        .contextPath("/app").servletPath("/main")
>>        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#unit-testing-spring-mvc

You will need to pass in the proper MediaType value of course.

Answer (score 0):

The mocked content type of the request is null, so spring mvc cannot determine which method it should invoke. If you set the value to application/html+xml, application/json, etc it should work correctly.

Comment: Where should I set this? Apart from setting some mock objects on the controller all I do is this inside a test method: `RestAssuredMockMvc.given().when().get("cars/1").then().statusCode(404);`